# User32.dll's SendMessage method returns wrong ListViewGroup id

Tags: c#, winforms, user32

I want to handle a group header click event. I used information from [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/eccdf58a-dd06-4ae3-908d-5f5863c01d64/) to achieve my goal. The application properly recognizes mouse click on the group header, the problem actually is, as the title states, that the group id returned by SendMessage method is wrong for some of the groups.

My ListView (on which I tested the code) looks like this:

```
Group 1
  Item 1.1
  Item 1.2
Group 2
  Item 2.1
  Item 2.2
Group 3
  Item 3.1
```

Basically, it works fine until I click on the 2nd or 3rd group. When clicking group headers SendMethod returns the following values: 0 for `Group 1`, 2 for `Group 2` and 3 for `Group 3`.

Here's the WndProc method implementation:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        bool passMessage = true;

        if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            Point hitPoint = LParamToPoint(m.LParam);
            LVHITTESTINFO lvHitTestInfo = new LVHITTESTINFO();
            lvHitTestInfo.pt.x = hitPoint.X;
            lvHitTestInfo.pt.y = hitPoint.Y;

            int rtn = SendMessage(listView.Handle, LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST, -1, ref lvHitTestInfo);
            if (rtn != -1)
            {
                if (((lvHitTestInfo.flags & LVHITTESTFLAGS.LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER) == LVHITTESTFLAGS.LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER))
                {
                    passMessage = false;

                    string groupName;
                    if (rtn == listView.Groups.Count)
                        groupName = "default";
                    else
                        groupName = listView.Groups[rtn].Header;
                    GroupClicked.Invoke(listView, new ListViewInterceptorEventArgs(rtn, groupName));
                }
            }
        }

        if (passMessage)
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

I want to display content related to the chosen group, so I need to know which one was clicked. I'm using Windows 8. If anyone could direct me to a solution, I'll be very thankful. If you need any other information, please let me know and I will provide you with it.

P.S. In my app I add groups dynamically, like this:

```
                ListViewGroup contactsGroup = new ListViewGroup(group.id, group.name);
                contactsGroup.Name = group.id;
                contactsGroup.HeaderAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                lvContacts.Groups.Add(contactsGroup);
                for (int i = 0; i < group.users.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(group.users[i]);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(group.userStatus[i] ? "ONLINE" : "offline");
                    lvi.Group = contactsGroup;
                    lvContacts.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
```

The same WndProc method implementation works just fine in another program, which I wrote just to test this and in which I added the groups via the designer, though.

Comment: This is going to require a lot of work to repro with very low odds of success.  If you need help debugging this then you will have to create a minimum repro project with this problem and post it to a file sharing service.

Comment: Yea, I guess you got a point there. I thought maybe someone had the same problem and found a solution, thus would save me some hours, but I guess I'll have to battle it on my own. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I know this is 3 years old, but I've just come up against the same thing. I've found a way that makes it work but it completely baffles me as to what is going on. If you create *all* the ListViewGroup objects first and then add them to the listview - it works...for me at least. I can post a code-sample if anyone wants.

Comment: Hi David. This is a long forgotten solution, but when I have the time to find the sources, adopt to new VS/.NET and other stuff, I'll check it :) Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*June 2019* : This is still an issue an Microsoft clearly hasn't fixed it yet !

But thanks to **David Amey** we have a fix.
You first need to create and add all your groups to the listview

```
Dim MyLvg As ListViewGroup = New ListViewGroup With {.Header = "MyGroup1", .Name = "MyGroup1"}
MyLsv.Groups.Add(MyLvg)
```

**Only after that** will you be able to add items.

---

I **also** figured out, at this stage it won't work if you declare a new ListViewItem from scratch and add it, but rather here you **need to go through your existing ListView instance to create it**. Then just link your Lvi to your Lsv and you're all set.

```
Dim MyLvi As ListViewItem = MyLsv.Items.Add("This is my new item")
MyLvi.Group = MyLvg
```

---

On a final note, let me add that I've tested 6 ways to link ListViewItems to ListViewGroups and all were working ok

```
MyLvi.Group = MyLvg
MyLvi.Group = MyLsv.Groups(0)
MyLvi.Group = MyLsv.Groups("MyGroup1")

MyLvg.Items.Add(MyLvi)
MyLsv.Groups(0).Items.Add(MyLvi)
MyLsv.Groups("MyGroup1").Items.Add(MyLvi)
```

This could seems logical, but we still don't get those bugs so I preferred to double check.

Using this way of creating and linking Groups and Items will definitely ensure you to avoid this "Bad Group Id" problem from LVHITTESTINFO